# PhpMyadmin ошибка

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

У меня ошибка в phpMyadmin, пропали все базы данных. Когда только захожу пишет

> "#1143 - SELECT command denied to user 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost'
>   for column 'default_collation_id' in table ‘character_sets'', пытаюсь
>   зайти в базы данных выводить "#1143 — SELECT command denied to user
>   'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' for column 'default_collation_id' in
>   table ‘character_sets'".

Как я поняла у меня нет прав для входа, но я же с root захожу и раньше все было норм

Comment: если перевести сообщение об ошибке,то будет что-то вроде "не хватает прав на SELECT у  'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' ". Надо проверить права у этого юзера и выдать их. dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Comment: да, я  в принципе поняла, но как выдать самой себе права если их нет?

Comment: под рутом зайти

Comment: в этом как раз проблема, у меня есть единственный аккаунт он же root, и у меня нет почему то прав

Comment: это не root, это mysql.infoschema . в общем или дайте себе права или просите доступ от root

Comment: хорошо я вроде бы поняла, вы не могли бы немного объяснить как именно дать себе те права которые нужны ?

Comment: что то типа GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;   - читайте про то как дать права пользователю

Comment: спасибо большое, исправила!

Comment: phpMyadmin хорош для новичков но не удобный. скачайте heidiSQL там легче и помогает лучше познать СУБДД